# How do i pass doinbackground response to Onpostexecute in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is my Doinbackground,and for some reason i don't find anything in String s of postexecute,am i doing anything wrong ??,btw calling this asynctask by new mytask().execute(Url,dum) from another class

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String email = strings[0];

            Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
            // String json1="{'dashboardData':'SERVICE_GET_CCAVENUE_KEY','userName':'abcd'}";

            RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("REQUEST_TYPE_SENT","SERVICE_FORGOT_USER_PASSWORD")
                    .add("phone",strings[1])//"+91 - 9999991212")
                    .add("device_token","gf")
                    .add("device_type","2")
                    .build();


            builder.url(strings[1])
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();



            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(strings[1])
                    .addHeader("decode","2")
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();

            try {

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

               // JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                //op[0] = obj.getString("user_id");
                writeToFile("response="+response.body().string());
                return response.body().string();

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            return null;
        }

 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            //Context context = getApplicationContext();
            //CharSequence text = s;
            //int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            //toast.show();
           // Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HomepageNormal.class);
           // startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: move  return null;  code inside of catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: still the same :/

Comment: post onpost execute and logcat

Comment: print url of calling by responce.request().url() check its correct or not

Comment: added onpostexecute

Comment: @Shiva im getting the response all right in doinbackground

Comment: just a guess, you are calling response.body().string() twice. maybe response is getting cleared in writetofile function. So save it in new variable and use it in writetofile function and return the variable to onpostexecute(); I have posted the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
writeToFile("response="+response.body().string());
return response.body().string();
```

try using this

```
String tmpVariable = response.body().string();
writeToFile("response="+tmpVariable );
return tmpVariable ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must ref this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) how to use async task first...

Answer (score 0):

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

          // Do stuff
          return result;//This result will  be passed to your OnPostExecute
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

              /*result is the result from doInBackground
               use this result to do stuffs*/

    } 

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

Comment: and what would i be doing wrong then,its the same that i have i guess

Comment: I think there us a exception encountered in your try catch block and thus every time  your doInBackground returns null , try returning something else like return"Test1" and in postExecute Toast the result

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Retrofit getRetro() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain
                            .request()
                            .newBuilder()
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            }).build();

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Global.DOT_NET_IP)//ur link like http://google.com
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
}


public void setData() {
    Call<JsonElement> call = getRetro().create(RestApi.class).setData("SERVICE_FORGOT_USER_PASSWORD", "7878009686", "gf", "2");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {

            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().toString());//ur response
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

RestApi.class

```
@GET("set_data_url")
Call<JsonElement> setData(
        @Query("REQUEST_TYPE_SENT") String REQUEST_TYPE_SENT,
        @Query("phone") String phone,
        @Query("device_token") String device_token,
        @Query("device_type") String device_type);
```

Comment: I'm a big noob,this all alien territory to me,could you edit your code according to my requirement,

Comment: how do i add headers to this ??

Comment: Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("parameter", "value").build();